# iReport last data row stretched issue

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using `iReports` to display records. Now my issue is that I wanted to display 25 records per page. I managed to achieve this, except for a small issue. The last row of the data table is stretched. I want to prevent this from happening.

I have tried `RelativeToBandHeight` for `stretchType`, but it does not yield the desired result.

This is my code:

```
<detail>
    <band height="129">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() == 1? new Boolean(true) : new Boolean(false)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </band>
    <band height="16">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() == 1? new Boolean(true) : new Boolean(true)]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="203" y="0" width="239" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="b94e5787-eba7-48ea-a14d-192bf9988a67"/>
            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Tahoma" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="11" y="0" width="192" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0d42d5e0-f85a-4648-9b1b-f86085e2055b"/>
            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Tahoma" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="442" y="0" width="103" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="53c1a819-b7ae-4861-9eaa-819dc4fbc1c0"/>
            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Tahoma" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{grade}.equals("")?("(-)"):($F{grade})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <break>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="16">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Boolean((int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue())%25==0)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>    
        </break>        
    </band>
</detail>
```

And this is the output of the given code:

[image]

Comment: edit appearance and fix spelling/lingo

Answer (score 0):

You could place the 3 textfield elements together in a frame, and keep the break element as it is, outside the frame.